# How to grant permission to specifc role to perform CRUD operations on a particular content type only?

Tags: nodes, users

I've set up different roles and in my site and I want a specifc role to grant permission to perform CRUD(create, Read, Update, Delete) operations on a particular content type only. But I can't find any such option in drupal admin.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Create, update and delete can be controlled via admin > people > permissions for that content type. View permissions requires a node access module (e.g content access)  or custom node access code to control.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. And create action assign role.

[How to use.](http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-send-follow-emails-using-rules-scheduler-drupal-7)

Answer (score 0):

A module specifically designed for this and very easy to use is the [Content Access Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access). When you use this, you will see that there are new per-content type permissions in the permissions configuration page.